# Htaccess redirect https and http and custom url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I am new to htaccess and even though I get the part to have a custom URL, I can't manage to figure out https redirect combined with having a custom URL. All the options I have found online have given me a redirect loop.

So, suppose I have a page called: mysite.com/hello.php and another one called mysite.com/bye.php.

I want [mysite.com/hello.php](http://mysite.com/hello.php) to become [mysite.com/one-hello](http://mysite.com/hello.php) and bye.php to become mysite.com/two-bye. This is how I have it in my htaccess now:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^one-hello$ hello.php
RewriteRule ^two-bye$ bye.php
```

But now I want hello.php to always show up as https but bye.php to always show up as http. How could I write all of these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^one-hello$ hello.php [L]
RewriteRule ^two-bye$ bye.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^hello\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^bye\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works perfectly. I was using RewriteRule ^one-hello$ ... That's why it wouldn't work. I am new to stackoverflow but I think I need to accept your answer. I will research how to and do it. Thanks!

Comment: You can accept the answer after few more minutes by clicking on green tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: I accepted it. But I have a quick question. If I have many pages like hello and bye, I have to rewrite RewriteCond %{HTTPS} every single time before each RewriteRule? Or is there a way around it? Without rewriting it, I get a loop again.

Comment: You can use regex to include multiple URIs into one like `RewriteRule ^(hello|hello1|hello2)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]`